# Can we use UmlStateMachineModelFactory inside a StateMachineBuilder

Tags: spring-statemachine

I am using  StateMachineBuilder to create state machine , coz I needed to use it programatically to configure states and transitions.

But due to some requirement change my configuration is almost constant and now I wanted to use eclipse uml modelling since I no longer need to build state machine dynamically or programatically.
To avoid big code rework I thought of using UmlStateMachineModelFactory inside builder like below.

```
Builder<String, String> builder = StateMachineBuilder
                .<String, String> builder();
        builder.configureConfiguration()
        .withConfiguration()
        .autoStartup(false)
        .listener(listener())
        .beanFactory(
                this.applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory());



builder.configureModel().withModel().factory(new UmlStateMachineModelFactory("classpath:model2.uml"));
```

1) Is it legal in state machine, if so how can I attach entry actions for each state?

Currently using the builder I am using the below code for attaching entry actions for each state

stateConfigurer.state("State1", this.state1EntryAction, null);

```
// State1EntryAction is  @Autowired inside my controller class  and
// State1EntryAction   implements Action<String, String> and
// annotated with @Component (org.springframework.stereotype.Component)
```

2) Can i give the name of entry action class inside the uml model, order to attach entry actions for each stage? if so how can i do that in eclipse papyrus.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docs are probably a little unclear of this(especially if user is not familiar with papyrus and uml concepts). I'd start by studying uml test sources in [uml xml test files](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine/blob/master/spring-statemachine-uml/src/test/resources/org/springframework/statemachine/uml) how actions/guards are referenced from uml into a runtime resolving. Things become more clear when you see those using real papyrus uml modeler.

On default guard/action will resolve as equivalent bean name from an application context, but there is a way to hook additional instances manually(i.e. if guard/action is not defined as a bean).

This test [testSimpleFlat2()](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine/blob/ec21afc131ae05b63b3d63ecb60e45d741369b05/spring-statemachine-uml/src/test/java/org/springframework/statemachine/uml/UmlStateMachineModelFactoryTests.java#L89) will register additional actions/guards. These are resolved via `StateMachineComponentResolver` interface and internally instance of `DefaultStateMachineComponentResolver` will resolve from `BeanFactory` if it's known but user can add secondary `DefaultStateMachineComponentResolver` as demonstrated in that test.